# How to exclude SQL query results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, each with a column `product_id`, I would like to do a query which will exclude results for products with a `product_id` found in both tables.

**Pseudo example:**

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE product_id NOT IN table2
```

Comment: `select t1.* from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.product_id = t2.product_id where t2.product_id is null`

Answer (score 1):

If you can have product_ids in both tables that are not present in the other table, then you have to do a union, since mysql does not support full outer join:

```
select t1.product_id, 't1' as table_name
from table1 t1 left join table2 t2
on t1.product_id = t2.product_id where t2.product_id is null 
union
select t2.product_id, 't2' as table_name
from table1 t1 right join table2 t2
on t1.product_id = t2.product_id where t1.product_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from table1 
where product_id not in (select product_id from table2) as p;
```

Comment: I thought this should be a comment, rather than a answer. Always use aliases to reference tables in columns. `select * from table1 as t1
where t1.product_id not in (select t2.product_id from table2 as t2);`

Comment: This is an answer to the question and there is no need to alias table names, unless you want to reference the same table twice, which is not the case here.